# Can't run converted exe in other PC

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, exe, pyinstaller

I have converted a python file to exe using pyinsatller. When I run the exe file in my pc, it is working fine. But when I try to install in other PC, It is showing error:

The error is:

```
procedure entry point urct.terminate couldnot be located in dll api-msi-win-crt-runtime
```

How to fix this?

Comment: When you create a python exe file, you have a lot of dll, you can't extract only .exe file, you need all these files on same directory. Like doing the exe converter.

Comment: @– deon cagadoes . YesI have copied the exe folder into other pc. Then also it is not working

Comment: The other pc have ``api-msi-win-crt-runtime`` DLL ?

Comment: You probably need a microsoft redistributable package. But I can't tell which version exactly. I would try from 2010 to 2017.

Comment: Did you read [platform specific notes for windows](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=redistributable#windows)?